# Eclipse shortcut to comment out code doesn't work anymore

Tags: eclipse, comments

I used to be able to use ctrl+7 to comment out code, but all the sudden it doesn't work like that anymore. Instead I get a small window popup at the lower right corner, saying only `Toggle Comment   Ctrl+7`. If I use the shortcut again it appears to close and then reopen the window. If I press enter nothing happens. If I double click it, it does toggle comment. How can I fix it?

Here's how it looks: [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somehow "Restore Defaults" at Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys solved the problem, even though all "toggle comment" commands were already bound to ctrl+7.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that shortcuts on your Eclipse have been changed. You can always change the shortcuts by going to Eclipse Preferences -> General -< Keys. Type "comment" in search box and change the shortcuts for what you are interested. I guess you are interested in Add Block Comment which usually is "Ctrl+Shift+/". [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9sJ5.png)

Comment: Nope, "toggle comment" is the one I was after, and it was already bound correctly. But somehow restoring to default solved the problem.